# Как правильно обработать select

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос такой. Необходимо чтобы в форме было поле где указывается есть ли дети, а если да, то сколько их и их возраст. Реализовал это так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 6, i, j, el, child;
    var container = $('#child-amount');

    el = $(document.createElement('select')).attr('class', 'child__amount-item');
    container.append(el);
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        child = $(document.createElement('option'));
        child.attr('value', i + 1);
        child.text(i);
        el.append(child);
    }

    el.change(function() {
        count = parseInt($(this).find(':selected').text());

        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            el = $(document.createElement('select')).attr('class', 'child__old').attr('id', 'child__old_' + i);
            container.append(el);

            for (j = 0; j < 18; ++j) {
                child = $(document.createElement('option')).attr('id', 'child__old-item' + j);
                child.attr('value', j);
                child.text(j);
                el.append(child);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="child-amount" id="child-amount"></div>
```

Но понимаю, что это не совсем корректно реализовано, так как если выбрать сначала что детей скажем 2, то добавляется 2 `select`a, но если тут же изменить количество детей на 1, то будет 3 `select`a, то есть они просто приплюсуют. Кто подскажет как избежать этого? И еще необходимо, чтобы если количество детей больше 0, то к `select` с классом `child__amount-item` к классу добавлялась приставка, скажем _have - нужно для стилизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И не назначайте элементам никакие `id`, они Вам не нужны.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 6,
    i, j, el, child;
  var container = $('#child-amount');

  el = $(document.createElement('select')).attr('class', 'child__amount-item');
  container.append(el);
  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    child = $(document.createElement('option'));
    child.attr('value', i);
    child.text(i);
    el.append(child);
  }

  el.change(function() {
    var count = parseInt($(this).val());

    if (count > 0)
      $(this).addClass("child-have");
    else
      $(this).removeClass("child-have");

    var $ages = container.find(".child__old");

    // 1. delete if we have more than selected
    for (i = $ages.length - 1; i >= count; i--) {
      $($ages[i]).remove();
    }

    // 2. create if we have fewer than selected
    for (i = $ages.length; i < count; ++i) {
      el = $(document.createElement('select')).attr('class', 'child__old');
      container.append(el);

      for (j = 0; j < 18; ++j) {
        child = $(document.createElement('option'));
        child.attr('value', j);
        child.text(j);
        el.append(child);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="child-amount" id="child-amount"></div>
```

Comment: Игорь, спасибо огромное.Все работает вроде так как надо. +1 к ауре добра!

Comment: @Deniskins Главное, чтобы Вам все было понятно в этом коде. Вам все понятно?

Comment: Да, Игорь, все понятно. Спасибо огромное. Вот только на последний момент уделите пожалуйста время. Для стилизации мне необходимо к классу child__amount-item добавить еще класс. Если я добавляю его так $(".child__amount-item").toggleClass("child-have"); , то он срабатывает, но при любом изменении selecta он так же срабатывает и удаляется. Подскажите пожалуйста как это обработать.

Comment: Поясню, добавление класса нужно, чтобы если появляется select с возрастом, то select с количеством детей уходил влево, иначе они плохо читаемы на странице

Comment: @Deniskins добавил. Посмотрите, я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: Да да!Именно так! Ну все, к ауре +100 и титул Гуру.-) Спасибо большое. На примерах подобных гораздо быстрее понимаешь как это реализовывать в будущем. Потому что большинство людей просто копипастом занимается, а хочется понимать. Теперь буду знать. Более не беспокою! Низкий поклон за пояснение и за то, что показали.

Comment: @Deniskins На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

У вас такое происходит потому что при каждом новом выборе у вас добавляются записи.

Предлагаю такой алгоритм.

1. Есть текущее количество детей (изначально 0).
2. Если пользователь установил некоторое, новое количество детей, то смотрим это больше или
   меньше текущего значения.
3. Если больше то просто добавляем разницу.
4. Если меньше то стираем разницу. Кроме того если пользователь уже
   заполнил данные, то можно у него спросить уверен ли он что хочет
   затереть их.

Добавлять вы уже научились, теперь необходимо научиться стирать лишнее.

Comment: Хм..а в коде как реализовать не подскажешь?Я не мега силен в js. Буду весьма признателен..

Comment: Прошу в коде изобразить потому как, да, больше желание научиться и понять, чем копировать, но без видимости как делать ничего не поймешь.

Comment: @Deniskins Чтобы облегчить задачу отвечающим, создайте рабочий пример, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: Как просил Игорь, добавил фрагмент кода